# Why do functions that throw exception not pass with function_name.should.throw(error)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

We have the following working test example:

```
"use strict";

var should = require("chai").should();

var multiply = function(x, y) {
  if (typeof x !== "number" || typeof y !== "number") {
    throw new Error("x or y is not a number.");
  }
  else return x * y;
};

describe("Multiply", function() {
  it("should multiply properly when passed numbers", function() {
    multiply(2, 4).should.equal(8);
  });

  it("should throw when not passed numbers", function() {
    (function() {
      multiply(2, "4");
    }).should.throw(Error);
  });
});
```

There's no explanation on why the second test needs to be run with the hack

```
(function() {
      multiply(2, "4");
    }).should.throw(Error);
```

If you run it like

```
it("should throw when not passed numbers", function() {
      multiply(2, "4").should.throw(Error);
  });
```

the test fails

```
  Multiply
    ✓ should multiply properly when passed numbers
    1) should throw when not passed numbers
```

But running the function as a regular node script does fail:

```
Error: x or y is not a number.
    at multiply (/path/test/test.js:7:11)
```

So I don't get why the `should` doesn't pick up the fact that it throws error.

What is the cause of needing to wrap this in anonymous `function() { }` call? Is it do to tests running asynchronously, or scope or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chai is regular JavaScript, not magic. If you have an expression `a().b.c()` and `a` throws, `c()` can’t catch it. `c` can’t even run. The engine can’t even know what `c` *is*, because `a` didn’t return a value whose `.b.c` could be looked up; it threw an error instead. When you use a function, you have an object on which to look up `.should`, which in turn gives you an object on which to look up and call `.throw`.

That’s why it *can’t* do that, but from an API point of view, there’s nothing wrong: `.should.throw` is just an assertion on a function instead of a function call.

I’d also recommend using Chai’s `expect`, which doesn’t insert itself into `Object.prototype` to give the appearance of magic.